# Dual of axiom of choice

Tags: category-theory, axiom-of-choice, topos-theory

The (internal version of) **axiom of choice**, stated in the language of category theory says that every epimorphism splits - i.e., every epimorphism has a section.

Now, just like any other category theoretic statement, it has a dual statement which can be produced by inverting all of the arrows. Thus, dual of axiom of choice, we which we dub **axiom of co-choice** in this question, states that every monomorphism is split -- i.e. has a retraction.

Now, without any assumptions beyond ZF, this holds in the topos *Set*. However, like axiom of choice, it fails in *Top*. Off the top of my head, I don't know it failing in any other relevant category.

However, despite looking for some more information on it, there seems to be no literature studying axiom of co-choice. So, my question are these:

**Is the axiom of co-choice not mathematically interesting? Is there any philosophical or mathematical justification for the dual of axiom of choice - a very interesting problem on its own - being boring? If it is truly a boring or trivial result, what classes of categories do satisfy it - i.e. what are some statements or requirements which are equivalent to it?**

Comment: It fails in Ab as well. The monomorphism $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ given by multiplication by $2$ doesn't split.

Comment: It fails in Set: the monomorphism $\varnothing \to \{\star\}$ does not split.

Comment: Right, so it only works for inhabited sets, which I missed. So, I guess I have to go back and see if any topos satisfies it at all.

Comment: It would work in $k$-Mod, where $k$ is a field (i.e., vector spaces over $k$).

Comment: It doesn't apply to any topos, because the map $\emptyset \rightarrow *$ isn't split. I think I got a partial answer to my second question.

Comment: Wait, how can you find a left inverse to a monomorphism $i : A \hookrightarrow B$ without choice, i.e. without choosing an element in $A$ where to send the complementary of $\text{im } i$?

Comment: @Fosco In the case of a monomorphism, there is no actual invocation of choice when constructing the left inverse, because we know there is at most one $x$ for any $y$ such that $i(x) = y$. For epimorphisms, we have to actually choose an element from the subset of elements $i$ sends to some $y$, so choice is required.

Comment: What I mean (and it might be a very stupid question) is that a monomorphism of sets $i :A \hookrightarrow B$ has a left inverse $g : B \to A$ defined sending an element $b$ in the image of $i$ to the unique $a$ such that $ia=b$, and an element on the complement of said image to some $a_0$. How do you choose such an $a_0$?

Comment: @Fosco Actually, that is an interesting point. It's a highlight of difference between constructive and classical mathematics. In classical mathematics, this is perfectly valid, because by law of excluded middle, we can rule out the complement of image of $i$ being empty, so by definition there is *some* $a_0$ in its complement. But in constructive mathematics, we cannot make this assertion, so injective functions don't necessarily have left inverses.

Comment: To continue, I wonder whether the converse is true? That is, does injective function on a nonempty set having a left-inverse imply LEM? I guess I have to verify whether this is the case.

Comment: Indeed, this is exacty what I wanted to imply! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Every epimorphism splits" and "every monomorphism splits" turn out to be equivalent for abelian categories: both conditions are equivalent to the condition that every short exact sequence splits. You might call such an abelian category semisimple, although the discussion at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327899/name-for-abelian-category-in-which-every-short-exact-sequence-splits) suggests "split" instead. It is equivalent to the condition that $\text{Ext}^n = 0$ (as a functor) for $n \ge 1$. For example, the category $\text{Mod}(R)$ of $R$-modules satisfies this condition iff $R$ is semisimple.

So it is an interesting and natural condition in this setting, but 1) it's equivalent to its opposite and 2) nobody would call it "the axiom of cochoice" here.

It's also an interesting question in various settings to ask whether specific epimorphisms or monomorphisms split. In $\text{Top}$, for example, "does this epimorphism split?" specializes to asking whether a bundle has a section, and in $\text{CRing}$, "does this monomorphism split?" specializes to asking when a Diophantine equation has a solution. I wrote a blog post *[Topological Diophantine equations](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/topological-diophantine-equations/)* which discusses the analogy between these two cases in some more detail.

As another example, in abelian categories an object $P$ is projective iff every epimorphism with target $P$ splits, and dually an object $I$ is injective iff every monomorphism with source $I$ splits.